# Accesing Property files in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to spring and I am trying to read the values from properties file.

This is my Security XML:-

```
<beans:bean       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<beans:property name="location">
<beans:value>AuthProvider.properties</beans:value>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

and I am trying to access the properties in java class as follows but its returning nothing:

```
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("AuthProvider.properties");

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props2 = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

props2.setProperties(props);

for(String key : props.stringPropertyNames())

{

String value =  props.getProperty(key);   

System.out.println(key + " => " + value);

}
```

Can someone please tell me where I am goin wrong?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should show the error you get.

From other side to understand more it is better to read books and docs about a framework.
Regarding Spring you can find enough info here: https://spring.io/guides

Right now it isn't clear what is your general task.

To have just `properties` as bean it is enough to use:

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="AuthProvider.properties"/>
```

However you shouldn't forget that there is need to correctly specify the `location` for your file: is it on classpath, on file system, some external URL etc. Here is more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

At the same reference you can find out how to configure `<property-placeholder>` and why it is needed.

**UPDATE**

Just to load properties from file to the `Properties` object you do it correctly using `PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties`. But here the `resourceName` should be correct relative path to the file within CLASSPATH - and it will be loaded as resource by `ClassLoader`.

What is bad here, we don't know where is your `AuthProvider.properties`, and it says that you provide for it the wrong `path`.

Comment: My issue is when I want to access the key in property file it is returning NULL. Right now I just want to get access to the values in property files.
   System.out.println(props.stringPropertyNames()); returns nothing

Comment: Added the info about `classpath issue`

Comment: I have kept the file in WEB-INF folder. whose hirerchy is MultipleAuthManager/web-content/WEB-INF. 
I tried Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/MultipleAuthManager/web-content/WEB-INF/AuthProvider.properties"); but it is giving me following error :::-cannot be opened because it does not exist. So at what path I should Keep the file

Comment: Try just this: `/WEB-INF/AuthProvider.propert‌​ies`, when classpath root is your webapp

Comment: Tried that also but still giving me same error. Can you please suggest me anything else or any completely different startategy ?

Comment: Well. Then we should see your application structure, when it is deployed to the ServletContaier. Assume you `AuthProvider.propert‌​ies` isn't copied to war on build.

Comment: Add to your question a screenshot with WAR directory tree

Comment: Finally It worked copied my properties file into build folder where in class files get stored and gave this path /WebContent/AuthProvider.properties . Thanks Artem for your help

Comment: You are welcome! So, just close the question as closed accepting the answer. More success to you!